# How do I simplify my URLs with Apache (or DNS)?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, cname-record, rewrite, virtualhost

I'm running Apache 2.2 with WHM / cPanel. Let me know what other info you need to answer this question.

I want to set up some kind of forwarding/redirect so that the following occurs:

_http://appname.mydomain.com/   (ignore the underscore, couldn't post actual links)

actually sends you to

_http://mydomain.com:8072/appname/

This can be overt (your browser address bar changes) or not, it doesn't really matter (although if I get to pick I would prefer the address bar NOT change).

My initial thought was to use a CNAME, but I've since learned you can't include a port in your cname. Now I'm thinking I have to do something with my Apache VHOST?

I am very much a novice at apache / web server internal workings, but I know my way around a command line well enough.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html)? Something like this in your virtual host configuration should do the trick (not tested)

```
<VirtualHost appname.mydomain.com>
    ProxyPass / http://mydomain.com:8072/appname/
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure to read the docs as I haven't used it myself.

Comment: If you do use the Proxy module, learn from my mistake. DO NOT ENABLE ProxyRequests (ie set it to "On"). You will turn into a HTTP proxy. The documentation says your server could be used to send email, which is very misleading as it can do a whole lot more than just that.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't have a redirect page sitting on http://appname.mydomain.com bouncing you to the new page?

(Untested) example in PHP, since I'm a PHP type of guy.

`<?php header('Location: http://newurl:newport'); ?>`

Comment: Hmmm OK, my chunk of code doesn't want to be displayed :/ (presumably from lack of backticks)

Comment: You're missing a Location: in that header, so it would be header('Location: http://newurl:newport');

Comment: Arg so I was (updated) - I did that in my head, honest! iPhones weren't designed for this!!

Comment: It's a better idea to use `proxypass` to make it seamless, or a redirect (`mod_rewrite` or `mod_redirect`) so users get the 301 moved. SEO generally likes this better anyway, if you're worried about that at all.